# After form sent, values from select inputs are stored in request variable with an extra ' " '

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

The select input:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="server_status">Server status</label>
    <select class="form-control {{$errors->has('server_status') ? 'is-invalid' : ''}}" name=server_status">
        <option value="tba">Not open yet</option>
        <option value="beta">Beta testing is on</option>
        <option value="running" selected>Up and running</option>
    </select>
    @if($errors->has('server_status'))
    <small class="text-danger">{{$errors->first('server_status')}}</small>
    @endif
</div>
```

The store method:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, $this->validate_rules);
    $server = Server::create(request()->all());
    Log::add_log('SERVER_REGISTERED', $server->id, $server->user_id);
    return redirect()->route('server.index');
}
```

For some reason, values coming from select can be accessed like that, with an extra ":

```
var_dump($request['server_status"']); //Coming from select input
var_dump($request['server_name']); //Coming from text input
```

All other inputs working well. Any help or hint would be appreciated.

Comment: check your select box name `name=server_status"`,  name value does not have starting quotation, It should be `name="server_status"`

Comment: yes that was the problem, it's a silly typo from me, I couldnt notice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change :

```
<select class="form-control {{$errors->has('server_status') ? 'is-invalid' : ''}}" name=server_status">
```

Into this :

```
<select class="form-control {{$errors->has('server_status') ? 'is-invalid' : ''}}" name="server_status">
```

the problem is

`name=server_status"` is equal to `name='server_status"'`

Comment: Yes this is it, it's a typo, that I was blind for :D Thank you very much for your help, I will accept your answer, as soon stack lets me :)